# How to add existing data types to SharePoint feature schema.xml

Tags: sharepoint, schema, content-type, sharepoint-feature

I have made a custom SharePoint feature based on default Document Library. Basically I made a copy of the DocumentLibrary folder and modified it and all the required xml files to make it unique library type. Now I need to add link to its supported content types but it seems not be working. I managed to do this via the web GUI but I need to add it straight to the CAML definition.

As far as I know the Link type should be added as ContentTypeRef tag to the schema.xml. I have the following markup inside the MetaData tag in the beginning of the file:

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101">
    <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
  </ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0105" />
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01010A" />
</ContentTypes>
```

Is there any other setup required to allow the link type? The above code doesn't enable links. The ID values of ContentTypeRef are from ctypewss.xml file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your content type refs are wrong 
follow  the link from this url that might be help for you [Content Type IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543822.aspx)

Comment: Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896%28v=office.12%29.aspx (Base Content Type Hierarchy) it seems the ID values are correct. 0x01010A = LinkToDocument. 0x0105 = Link. Don't know why they don't work though.

Comment: It seems that enabling "Allow management of content types" to Yes enables the content types defined in schema.xml. Now I just need to figure out how to enable it in the schema itself. The problem is now that SharePoint gives an error (Value does not fall within the expected range.) when trying to create a link (but still creates it) and the new link doesn't work but display an error page (An unexpected error has occurred).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091(v=office.12).aspx        EnableContentTypes = "TRUE" | "FALSE"